# Why Must This Function That Escapes HTML Have A Parameter Initially Set That Is An Empty String - PHP?

Tags: php, function, escaping, function-parameter

I've seen a function that escapes outputted HTML onto a page, by returning the `htmlspecialchars()` method inside a function:

```
 function escape($string="") {
      return htmlspecialchars($string);
 }
```

The tutorial said to always set the parameter to an empty string: `$string = ""`

Why must you do this? Surely the following function would work just as well?

```
 function escape($string) {
      return htmlspecialchars($string);
 }
```

In both cases you would call the function with something like the following after you have fetched a row/record from a database:

```
$db_id = escape($row['id']);
```

I don't understand why the parameter must initially be given the value of an empty string?

Anna

Comment: `I don't understand why the parameter must initially be given the value of an empty string?` .... $string="" is not setting any initial value.  Its an option parameter. That means function escape() can be called without params. Try

Comment: HI @IndraKumarS — So the second version of the function I gave is just as valid then?

Comment: It is just as valid. the only difference is that the second method signature _requires_ a parameter be sent in or it will throw a fatal error. The first signature allows the method to be called with or without a parameter by designating a default value of "". Admittedly, allowing no parameter here makes little practical sense so I would argue that the second is the most correct way to write this particular method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the code blocks given below

**function 1: Param is optional**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
function escape($string="") {
      return htmlspecialchars($string);
 }

echo escape();
?>
```

**function 1: Param is NOT optional**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
function escape($string) {
      return htmlspecialchars($string);
 }

echo escape();
?>
```

The second function will throw an error `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function escape(), 0 passed in`

Refer [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-157)

[image]